# Programmatic method of starting xd-admin and xd-container in spring XD

Tags: spring-xd

In a distributed setup, how do I programatically start containers?

More specifically, does there exist any API similar to deploying and undeploying streams for setting up and tearing down containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this via an API. Containers are only known to the cluster after they are started. Upon initialization, the container registers itself with ZooKeeper. Running a container requires XD to be installed on that host which is currently a manual process: download,unzip,configure, as is starting the container. Some automation of operations will likely be provided in a future release.

Comment: There is also the https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-ec2 project which you may find of interest

Comment: Thank you, I had come across the EC2 project too earlier, will take a close look.